# Column range sums with dplyr's `mutate`

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I want to sum up several rows in a data frame using `mutate`.

```
# Create the data - one row per order
f <- data.frame(
  customer = rep(c(1,2), each = 4), 
  order_type = rep(c("direct","express","air","regular"), 2), 
  count = sample(1:100, 8, replace = T))

# Spread the order data per-customer 
f <- f %>%
  spread(order_type, count, fill = 0) 

# Try to use mutate to sum up all types of orders
f %>%
  mutate(total = select(., air:regular) %>% rowSums)
```

I am expecting that the last call to mutate will populate a new column with the sum of the rows from `air` to `regular`. If I call `select(f, air:regular) %>% rowSums` outside of `mutate`, I get a vector with the sums. However, within `mutate`, I get the following error:

```
Error: Position must be between 0 and n
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In c(10, 14):c(96, 83) :
  numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
2: In c(10, 14):c(96, 83) :
  numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
```

I believe I am missing some fundamental point about `mutate` and its evaluation scheme.

I would like to understand how to perform this transformation with `dplyr`.

Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly it seems to work when using indices instead of column names as in `f %>% mutate(total = select(., 2:5) %>% rowSums)`

Comment: Would the following work (assuming `f` is not already spread) `f %>% group_by(customer) %>% mutate(tot = sum(count)) %>% spread(order_type, count)`

Comment: Hmm.. why don't you just do `f$total = f %>% select(air:regular) %>% rowSums`

Comment: This also seems to work: `f %>% mutate(total = select_(., "air:regular") %>% rowSums)` but of course there are easier ways to do this

Comment: @docendodiscimus: That is a very curious happenstance. I think I will stick to using the numbers for now. It would be nice to understand why named range does not work.

Comment: @steveb: Thanks for your solution. I think I would like to understand why the ungrouped mutate does not work

Comment: @Pekka: The question is more "why", not how. I came up with your solution as well, I just want my code to be consistent.

Comment: @Manbroski, yep, I wouldn't recomment that either. If you need to do it in a wide-format data I would rather do `f %>% mutate(total = rowSums(.[2:5]))` inside a dplyr chain. I'm not sure about the precise problem, but I have found it best not to nest different dplyr verbs into each other (like in this case you are using `select` inside `mutate`).

Comment: @Manbroski, also note that it works if you convert it to a `tbl_dt`: `f %>% tbl_dt %>% mutate(total = select(., air:regular) %>% rowSums)`. So perhaps it's an issue with dplyr's `tbl_df`

Comment: I like the `tbl_dt` solution. It allows to use the standard `dplyr` idioms in an expected manner. It does add an extra dependency, but that's not too much of a problem. Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: @Manbroski, it doesn't add any dependency as far as I can tell. It's still dplyr.. Please feel free to post all the comments in an answer yourself

Comment: @docendodiscimus: I had a clean installation with only `dplyr`, and it complained about missing `data.table` package.

Comment: @Manbroski, oh that's interesting. Didn't know that

Comment: Does anyone have any idea why `f %>%  mutate(total = rowSums(select(., -customer)))` excludes both `customer` and `air` from the row sum, while
`f %>%  mutate(total = rowSums(select(., -1)))` excludes only `customer` from the row sum and therefore gives the desired result? (Both of the above are without converting to `tbl_df` first.)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @docendo-discimus's comments, an acceptable solution is to use `tbl_dt`:

```
# Take note of the `tbl_dt` call:
f <- tbl_dt(data.frame(
  customer = rep(c(1,2), each = 4), 
  order_type = rep(c("direct","express","air","regular"), 2), 
  count = sample(1:100, 8, replace = T)))

# Spread the order data per-customer 
f <- f %>%
  spread(order_type, count, fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(total = select(., air:regular) %>% rowSums)
```

This requires an installation of `data.table`.

Another option is to use the programmable `select_` that uses strings:

```
# Spread the order data per-customer 
f <- f %>%
  spread(order_type, count, fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(total = select_(., "air:regular") %>% rowSums)
```

Last option is to use numeric subsetting:

```
f <- f %>%
  spread(order_type, count, fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(total = select(., 2:5) %>% rowSums)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xtabs` and `cbind` without loading external packages or reshaping:

```
cbind(xtabs(count ~ customer + order_type, f),
Total = margin.table(xtabs(count ~ customer + order_type, f),1))

  air direct express regular Total
1  41     29      79      89   238
2  53     95       5      90   243
```

**Update:** using `dplyr` as asked for by OP

Using your data with `set.seed(123)`:

```
 f %>% spread(order_type, count, fill = 0) %>%  group_by(customer) %>%
 cbind(.,total=rowSums(.[,-1]))

  customer air direct express regular total
1        1  41     29      79      89   238
2        2  53     95       5      90   243
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, I am specifically looking for a `dplyr` solution.